# Qutting a cocoa app after closing a window

Tags: cocoa, macos, ikpicturetaker

I have a small osx cocoa app that brings up an IKPictureTaker at start up, I would like for my application to quit after this picture taker is closed.  I read that I need to add this code to my NSWindowController class but I have no idea how to access this class (it shows up no where in my class list in XCode):`

```
-(BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom object that implements the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol and implement the [applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:) method there.

If you already have an application delegate (you more than likely do), just add it there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this method to your application delegate, whatever object that is.